# communication CLIENT / SERVER with secure connection SSL/TLS

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, tls1.2

```
import socket
import ssl
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import datetime
from os.path import split
```

the context used on both sides :
server side:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Inet is a connetor for the internet and sock_stream is a type of connection.
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server_socket.bind((self.get_ip(), 9999))  # Bind to the port and for the connecter be visible for everyone. socket.gethostname() de base
        self.server_socket.listen(5) # Listen for the connection and the number is the number of connections that can be made.
        self.context = None

    def ssl_context(self):
        self.context =  ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        self.context.load_cert_chain("CERT/cert-server.pem", "CERT/cert-key.pem")
```

and client side :

```
def configure_ssl_context_secure(self, server_ip, port):
        
        server_ip = self.get_ip()
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
        self.context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.ssl_client.cert_path, keyfile=self.ssl_client.path_privatekey)
        self.context.load_verify_locations(cafile="./CA/ca-cert.pem")
        self.secure_client_socket = self.context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname=server_ip)
        self.secure_client_socket.connect((server_ip, 9999))
```

[the mistake I make afterwards :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZahdA.png)
if someone would have a solution to my problem, with pleasure if you want more information on how I automate the sending of the request, how the server signs it with the CA then sends it back :)

I'm trying to implement an automated and secure RAT system with SSL/TLS. I've managed to set up a system for requesting a certificate on the client side and sending it to the server, which signs it with its CA and sends back a signed certificate.